# Get Max value from the column in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

**Input:**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty,resolution
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,2 qty,640*320
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,,200*200
282,apple,red,today,1 qty,,640*320
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,,,
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1 qty,,200*200
/283,banana,yellow,yesterday,1 qty,,200*200
```

**Output Json:**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty, resolution
282,apple,red,today,2 qty,2 qty, 640*320
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1 qty,,200*200
```

I would like to get the following:

- get the most frequent data for resolution column
- and to remove row that contain '/' in number column

For the qty:

```
(payload groupBy (key,index) ->(key.number ++ key.join_date)) mapObject {
   a: {
       number: $[0].number,
       fruit: $[0].fruit,
       colour: $[0].colour,
       join_date:$[0].join_date,
       avginqty: if((sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avginqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else "", 
       avgoutqty: if((sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avgoutqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else ""
   }
} pluck $
```

Comment: "get the most frequent data for resolution column" what does this mean? Please clarify the criteria. It is not clear how the expected output matches this criteria.

Comment: based on the number and fruit, so for example there are 2 of 640*320 for number 282 and fruit apple

Comment: So, you want to group by number and fruit, then count the different resolutions and get the group where the count is the max? How did you pick the one that has avgoutqty='2 qty' and not the one that was empty? Or it's any from that group? Also, for 282-bananas, the amount of '' and '200*200' is the same. Which one do you need to choose?

Comment: for the qty is : avginqty: if((sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avginqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else "", 
avgoutqty: if((sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avgoutqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else ""

Answer (score 2):

The script below would do what you are asking for but would not compare resolutions.

**Input**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty,resolution
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,2 qty,200*200
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,,640*320
282,apple,red,today,4 qty,,641*320
282,apple,red,today,1 qty,,640*320
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,,,
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,2 qty,,200*200
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1 qty,,200*200
/283,banana,yellow,yesterday, qty,,200*200
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var countOfResolution = (payload filter (!($.number contains "/")) groupBy ($.number ++ $.fruit ++ $.resolution) mapObject {
    (($.number[0]++"_"++$.fruit[0]) :
      { 
          resolution: $.resolution[0],
          occurence:$.resolution reduce (( curVal, acc= 0 ) -> 
    acc + 1 )
      }
    ) 
} orderBy -$.occurence)

---
payload filter (!($.number contains "/")) groupBy ($.number ++ $.fruit ++ $.resolution) mapObject {

        (a: {
            number: $[0].number,
            fruit: $[0].fruit,
            colour: $[0].colour,
            join_date:$[0].join_date,
            avginqty:  (if((sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) != 0 ) ($.avginqty sumBy (if(($ splitBy " ")[0] == "") 0 else ($ splitBy " ")[0]))/(sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else ""), 
            avgoutqty: if((sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avgoutqty sumBy (if(($ splitBy " ")[0] == "") 0 else ($ splitBy " ")[0]))/(sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else "",
            resolution: $.resolution[0] 
        }) if((countOfResolution.*"$($[0].number ++"_"++ $[0].fruit)" filter $.resolution != "")[0].resolution == $.resolution[0] )
    } 
    pluck $
```

**Output**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty,resolution
282,apple,red,today,2 qty,,640*320
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1.5 qty,,200*200
```

**Breakdown of the script**

1. Create an object to hold the resolution and its occurrences for each of number_fruit combinations.
2. Sort the resulting object in descending order to get the resolution that occurs the most on top.
3. Within the main script a row would be written if the current
   resolution is equal  to output from the object where the max
   occurring resolution is calculated for a given number_fruit
   combination.

Try this out and enhance it for your needs from here on. If you have a variation to this, please do ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Hi, How about if there are 2 resolution columns?

Comment: New question.. Like i mentioned earlier, you can't keep modifying your ask in the same question, the way you have been doing!!

Comment: As well be explicit in your ask , since beyond you nobody else knows what you are trying to solve. The more you express and make yourself clear on the ask, the easier it gets for others to take a shot at the solution.

Comment: Does this help you get to a solution ? If so please do accept it as the answer since it would help potentially someone who might have a similar problem at hand.

Comment: hi, i just realised the output doesnt have avgoutqty

Comment: Since the input does not have avgoutqty specified you don't see that in the input.. You can modify the input for different scenarios and test with the script.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a filter to your script to remove the slash: `payload filter (!($.number contains "/")`

Not that I have removed the `" qty"` strings from the input quantities so they can be summed. It doesn't make sense to me to mix numbers and strings in the same column.

Full script:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/csv
---
(payload filter (!($.number contains "/"))
    groupBy (key,index) ->(key.number ++ key.join_date))

    mapObject {
        a: {
            number: $[0].number,
            fruit: $[0].fruit,
            colour: $[0].colour,
            join_date:$[0].join_date,
            avginqty: if((sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avginqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else "", 
            avgoutqty: if((sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avgoutqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else ""
        }
    } 
    pluck $
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, how about the resolution? to use the most frequent data input based on number and join date

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what do you mean. Could you add more details and examples to the question?

Comment: based on grouping fruit and number, apple and 282, the resolution appear 1 time for 200*200, 2 times for 640*320, and therefore using the highest frequency of number of times which is 2 times of 640*320, so for the output it will be 640*320 for 282 number, apple fruit grouping. If it is null (no value), ignore this row, dont take the calculation into consideration.

Comment: In your groupBy clause in the script you are using number and join_date while what you are mentioning in the comment above is grouping by fruit and number. Which one needs to be considered for this use-case?

Is it as well possible for a fruit to have two different resolutions with the same count? For e.g. 2 occurrences of 640*320 and 2 occurrences of 200*200 each?

Comment: Hi, sorry, my bad, typo. Yes, group by fruit and number

Comment: Is it as well possible for a fruit to have two different resolutions with the same count? For e.g. 2 occurrences of 640*320 and 2 occurrences of 200*200 each?

Comment: yes, if thats the case, then choose the higher one? which is 640*320

Comment: 640*320 is a string and not a number.. How do you determine the higher between the two?

Comment: like 640> 200 and 320 > 200

Comment: you somewhere have a data problem that you are trying to absorb in the transformation and are making it more complex than it should be. Probably need to sanitize data before you apply DW to it.